# Dúvidas com as palavras "bastão" e "bastar"

Tags: significado, etimologia

Poderíeis dizer-me qual é o modo correcto de se dizer, *bater com bastão?* Seria *bastar?*

Outra dúvida que tenho é relacionada à etimologia: Parece-me que antigamente se escrevia *bastão*, em lugar da palavra usada actualmente, *bastam*. Existe relação entre estas duas palavras, *bastão* e *bastam*, em etimologia?

Comment: Pelo menos em português brasileiro não existe um verbo que signifique "bater com o bastão". "Bastar" significa "ser suficiente".

Comment: `antigamente, dizia-se: "Bastão", em lugar, da palavra usada actualmente: "Bastam"` <--- que palavra é esta? Um substantivo, ou um verbo?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

É bem possível que *bastar* e *bastão* tenham origem na mesma palavra latina, mas *bastar* não significa “bater com bastão”. A palavra que já foi usada com esse significado é *bastonar*. Vejamos isto ponto por ponto.

***Bastar*** tem dois significados relacionados [(vê Aulete)](http://www.aulete.com.br/bastar), ]: “ser suficiente”, e, conjugado pronominalmente, “ser autossuficiente” (*bastar-se a si mesmo*). As primeiras ocorrências do verbo que encontrei, neste [Corpus do Português](http://www.corpusdoportugues.org/x.asp), são do século XV, e já então era com o significado “suficiente” que era usado.

Eu desconhecia qualquer verbo com o significado de “bater com bastão”. Diria *dar uma bastonada* ou *dar umas bastonadas*. Pondo-me a inventar, pensei em ***bastonar***. Esta palavra não aparece em nenhum dicionário atual, mas procurando na net vemos que já foi e continua a ser usado, incluindo por autores de renome, como Eça de Queiroz e Luís da Câmara Cascudo (ênfase minha em todas as citações; grafia original):

> Se ele não paga, é ***bastonado***. De tal sorte que o felá, na convicção de que acaba sempre por ser ***bastonado***, nunca cede ao primeiro pedido…
>   [Eça de Queiroz, *O Egypto, Notas de Viagem, Relato da Inauguração do Canal do Suez*.](https://books.google.pt/books?id=E0-ZCgAAQBAJ&pg=PT31&dq=%22n%C3%A3o%20paga%20%C3%A9%20bastonado%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj6n5X-3tLMAhXMyoMKHUYdAvQQ6AEIHDAA#v=onepage&q=%22n%C3%A3o%20paga%20%C3%A9%20bastonado%22&f=false)
>
> […] Sebastião procurou encontrar-se com o imperador e exprobou-lhe a crueldade brutal. Diocleciano fê-lo perecer ***bastonado***, no dia 20 de janeiro de 288 em Roma.
>   [Luís da Câmara Cascudo, *Dicionário do Folclore Brasileiro*, 1962 (verbete *São Sebastião*)](http://www.jangadabrasil.com.br/janeiro29/pn29010b.htm)
>
> […] onde a autoridade manda ***bastonar*** o cidadão pela primeira falta que elle commette?
>   [Annaes do Parlamento Brazileiro, 1879.](https://books.google.pt/books?id=gUJXAAAAMAAJ&q=bastonar%20n%C3%A3o&dq=bastonar%20n%C3%A3o&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwid07Co5NLMAhUH94MKHRyGDNIQ6AEIUTAH)

Quanto à origem, segundo o dicionário Houaiss, *bastar* vem do latim vulgar *bastare*, “levar, suportar, bastar, ser suficiente”, que por sua vez vem do grego *bastázo*, “levantar um fardo e levá-lo”; *bastão* vem do latim vulgar *basto, -onis* (“bastão”), que por sua vez vem latim tardio *bastum*, “o que suporta”. Ora a palavra francesa *bâton* tem a mesma origem que *bastão*, e de acordo com o [CNRTL - Centre Nationale de Ressources Textuelles e Lexicales](http://www.cnrtl.fr/etymologie/baton) *bastum* é provavelmente um substantivo verbal de *bastare*, que segundo eles significava apenas *porter*, “levar, transportar”.

A ser assim, *bastão* e *bastar* teriam a mesma origem. De *levar, suportar* (*bastare*), viria *bastum*, “o que suporta”; e daí, *basto, -onis* já com o significado de *bastão* no sentido de cajado, uma vara de madeira em que um caminhante se apoia [(vê Aulete)](http://www.aulete.com.br/bast%C3%A3o). Entretanto, na transição do latim *bastare* para o português *bastar*, o significado de “levar, suportar” perdeu-se, e a ligação semântica entre *bastão* e *bastar* perdeu-se igualmente.

Nota no entanto que o CNRTL diz que *bastum* deriva *provavelmente* de *bastare*. Logo não há certeza e, cito o dicionário Houaiss (verbete ³bast-), «a cognação [de *bastum*] com **bastare* (ver ¹bast-), de acordo com Carominas, é duvidosa».

Mesmo que no latim estas palavras estivessem relacionadas, no português nunca estiveram. É verdade que já foi comum escrever *bastão* em vez de *bastam*, tal como *sirvão* em vez de *sirvam* (verbo *servir*) e *vejão* em vez de *vejam* (verbo *ver*); e também o contrário: já foi comum escrever *relaçam* em vez de *relação* e *coraçam* em vez de *coração*. Isto aconteceu porque durante séculos não houve uma norma ortográfica rígida, e cada autor escrevia como lhe parecia melhor. Nos exemplos seguintes, hoje escreveríamos, *coração, prendam, procedam, foram* e *vejam* (ênfase minha):

> [...] mostrou logo a grandeza e esforço de seu ***coraçam***.
>   [Garcia de Resende, *Vida e Feitos D'El-Rey Dom João II*, 1533.](https://pt.wikisource.org/wiki/Vida_e_Feitos_D%27_El-Rey_Dom_Jo%C3%A3o_Segundo/V)
>
> E achando, que não são tiradas, as tirem, e ***prendão***, e ***procedão*** contra os culpados, e contra os Juizes, que as não ***tirarão***, como for justiça. E se ja ***forão*** tiradas, ***vejão*** se ***procederão*** os ditos juizes contra os culpados em ellas, pela dita maneira.
>   [Duarte Nunes Lião, *Leis Extravagante*, 1569](https://books.google.pt/books?id=wp9FAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA414&dq=%22tiradas,%20vej%C3%A3o%20se%20proceder%C3%A3o%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjTq66K69DMAhVEmBoKHSz6D4oQ6AEIJjAA#v=onepage&q=%22tiradas%2C%20vej%C3%A3o%20se%20proceder%C3%A3o%22&f=false)

Comment: Obrigado  por ajudar, Jacinto!

Comment: Disseste que o dicionário Houaiss, apresenta bastão, como bastum; o que suporta. Pode-se dizer que, o que suporta, é o quanto basta, e que após isso; pode ser insuportável, além do bastante. Isto, me parece de grande relacionamento, entre bastão e bastar. Tens alguma opinião a respeito disto?

Comment: No latim *bastare* significava *suportar* (e outras coisas) e o [bastão suporta o caminhante](https://www.google.pt/imgres?imgurl=http%3A%2F%2Fthumbs.dreamstime.com%2Fz%2Fcaminhante-6887950.jpg&imgrefurl=http%3A%2F%2Fpt.dreamstime.com%2Ffoto-de-stock-caminhante-image6887950&docid=aBv6yuFsm6_pEM&tbnid=t0DGiOnnU6DKjM%3A&w=782&h=1300&bih=585&biw=1242&ved=0ahUKEwiq97vLu9HMAhXGWRoKHVcCAv0QMwiJAShiMGI&iact=mrc&uact=8). É só isto. Se o bastão for muito fino, o peso do caminhante pode ser insuportável para o bastão; não é o bastão que pode ser insuportável.

Comment: @renanlinux Nota que esta relação poderá ter existido no latim; no português, *bastar* não significa *suportar*. Também não sei como é que no latim o significado de *bastare* do original *levar, suportar* (vem de uma palavra grega com esse significado) para *ser suficiente*.

Comment: Obrigado pelo ajuda! Se o bastão não pode suportar o peso, não significa que ele é insuportável, insuportador; pois que, não presta suporte? Realmente, não sei até onde as palavras "bastão" e "bastar" estão ligadas, etimologicamente, mas, parece-me que na língua portuguesa, houve alterações, ao ponto de elas perderem parte de seus poderes.

Comment: A escolha entre _am_ e _ão_ [não era completamente arbitrária](http://www.apl.org.pt/docs/23-textos-seleccionados/7-Carvalho.pdf): no português do Centro e Sul, a terminação -ão ( -ANU) absorveu,
ao longo da época medieval, as terminações -ã, -an, -am ( -ANE; -ANT) e -õ, -on, -om ( -ONE; - NT), pelo que se registou a convergência das terminações nasais referidas para -ão, durante algum tempo representada graficamente por -ã, -an e am.

Comment: Relendo a citação do comentário anterior, de facto diz simplesmente que o _merger_ do som em _ão_ se representava também por _ã_, _an_ e _am_. Em todo o caso, antes de esse fenómeno fonético estar concluído (portanto no português medieval, posterior ao qual são as tuas citações), escreviam-se de formas diferentes.

Comment: @Artefacto Essa convergência refere-se às palavras grafadas atualmente com *ão*, certo? Porque nós hoje continuamos a grafar o som *ão* com *am* nas terminações verbais àtonas (*deram, eram*, etc.), e no passado já se grafou *ão* nestes casos também.

Comment: Sim, mas não estou a perceber o argumento. Estava apenas a dizer que as terminações não eram usadas indistintamente antes da convergência (na época medieval).